# [React-Navigation]How can i "Navigating without the Navigation prop" without Warning "You should only render one navigator explicitly in your app..."

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using "Navigating without the navigation prop" follow [offical doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html)

But i get warning `You should only render one navigator explicitly in your app, and other navigators should by rendered by including them in that navigator. Full details at: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/common-mistakes.html#explicitly-rendering-more-than-one-navigator`

I'm feeling that doc is conflict 
So, how can i fix this?

### `"react-navigation": "^2.11.2`

**UPDATE CODE**

This is my `TabNavigator` inside `StackNavigator`

```
const HomeTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
    CourseView: {
        screen: CourseView,
    },
    NotificationView: {
        screen: NotificationView,
    },
    SettingTab: {
        screen: SettingView,
    },
},
{
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: SECONDARY_COLOR,
        inactiveTintColor: PRIMARY_COLOR,
        showIcon: true,
        style: {
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
        },
        labelStyle: {
            display: "none"
        }
    },
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
    backBehavior: "initialRoute",
    lazy: true,
})
```

This is my `MainStackNavigator` i need assign "Navigating without Navigation prop" for TabNavigator (Warning show here)

```
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    HomeTabNavigator: {
        //I used "Navigating without navigation prop" here
        screen: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => <HomeTabNavigator ref={ref => SignedInTabService.setNavigator(ref)} />,
        // screen: HomeTabNavigator, Uncomment this won't show warning 'You should render.....'
        navigationOptions: { header: null }
    },

    NavCourseDetail: {
        screen: NavCourseDetail,

    },
},
{
    initialRouteName: "HomeTabNavigator",

    navigationOptions: {
        headerTintColor: "white",
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: PRIMARY_COLOR },
        headerBackTitle: null
    }
})
```

This is my `AppNavigator`, assign "Navigating without Navigation prop", too (warning show here)

```
class SignedInNavigator extends React.Component {
    settingStackRef = ref => {
        SignedInNavigatorService.setNavigator(ref)

    }
    render = () => {
        let x = HomeTabNavigator

        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                //FCMHandle is Firebase
                <FCMHandle {...this.props} />
                 //I used "Navigating without navigation prop" here, too
                <StackNavigator ref={this.settingStackRef} screenProps={{ numberNotif: this.props.numberNotif }} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    let numberNotif = state.auth.numberNotif
    return { numberNotif: numberNotif }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SignedInNavigator)
```

Comment: With only explicitly rendering one navigator in your app, they mean you should directly nest them, if you are using more than one navigator.  
To really see where the warning is coming from in your case, we'll need to see some code, though.

Comment: @stinodes I've just updated my code.

Comment: The problem with your code is that your navigators aren't the direct children of your parent navigators.

Comment: @stinodes: can you show me? at SignedInNavigator, my Navigator isn't the direct children (show warning with your explain). But At `HomeTabNavigator`, that is direct children (show warning without your explain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the react-navigation documentation, they say you should only directly nest your navigators.
What this means is that you should only nest your navigators like this if you want them to handle their nested states and actions correctly:

```
createStackNavigator({
  HomeTabNavigator: {
    screen: HomeTabNavigator, 
    navigationOptions: { header: null },
  },
  NavCourseDetail: {
    screen: NavCourseDetail,
  },
})
```

If you nest your navigators as follows

```
{
  HomeTabNavigator: { screen: () => <Navigator/> }
}
```

They are not nested directly and cannot access eachother.

There is no need to NOT have them nested directly in your case either.
You should probably use the "Navigating without Navigation prop"-technique on your root-level navigator, and let that one handle its children's navigation state.

```
const App = () => (
  <RootNavigator ref={NavigationService.setNavigator}/>
) 

NavigationService.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate('SomeNestedRoute'))
```

This should work just fine and there isn't really a reason I can think of right now to be using this on a nested navigator.

**In essence** only your root-navigator should be rendered using JSX (if you are rendering more than one navigator using JSX, it's a good indicator of you not nesting them correctly).

Comment: Thank for your explaining!
I think i implement nested navigator incorrect ways.